# How to manage view navigation in iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, sharedpreferences

Suppose, in my xiphone project on Xcode, I have one splash screen "a", 1st view "b", 2nd view "c", a button "back" on 2nd view. Now my task is, when my app will launch at the first time, splash screen will be launched. then "b" will be shown. Then go to "c". After that when again I will launch the app, the view "c" will be shown. And if I want to see the view "b", I have to press "back" button on view "c". Otherwise view "b" will never been shown.

This is my problem.
how could I solve the problem?

Comment: Why is this titled "About shared preferremce?" This has nothing to do with shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use notifications. Thus, in view controller C, you can:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // add notification to be informed if the app becomes active while
    // this view controller is active, and if so, to invoke the
    // appDidBecomeActive method.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)appDidBecomeActive
{
    // do whatever you want in this method. for example, if you did
    // a modal segue (or presentViewController) to present this
    // view controller's view, then you'd dismiss like thus:

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // when this view disappears, we should remove the observer on
    // the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
```